# Is it possible to quickly initiate When a Task Expires

Tags: 2010

Is it possible in SharePoint Designer 2010 task to initiate step **When a Task Expires** without waiting long time?

Minimal **DurationUnit** parameter is **Day(s)**. But my aim is to test step **When a Task Expires** as often as necessary within a short time without waiting next day.

Answer (score 0):

We can't change the default Duration.

You can add a new field to capture the duration in whatever format you like (hours or minutes). Add this field to the initiation form.

Then use that inside the workflow.

Comment: How can I initiate When a Task Expires this way?

Comment: You can customize the workflow in SharePoint Designer.

Comment: I understand that. For example, I can set any Due Date (for example past date), but task don't expire at once. Which concrete actions should I implement to test task expiration now, not next day?